# es6 import behavior is incorrect

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

I was working on a new project and previously I was doing something like 2 and can import `get` function without any problems. Somehow today 2 gives me undefined but 1 gives me the correct answer.  Does anyone know why is that?

p.s: my node version is 4.0.0

```
import api from "../../utils/APIUtils"; // --- 1
let get = api.get;
console.log(get); // function

import { get } from '../../utils/APIUtils'; // --- 2
console.log(get); // undefined now..

export default const APIUtils = {
  get(endpoint, query, options, done) { done(123) }
}
```

p.s: I saw 1-like usage here and they are working fine.

export default xxx: 
https://github.com/gpbl/isomorphic500/blob/master/src/utils/APIUtils.js

import from bracket:  https://github.com/gpbl/isomorphic500/blob/master/src/services/photo.js

Comment: Why is *what*? 1 and 2 mean different things, they cannot be used interchangeably.

Comment: The behavior is correct. If it really ever worked then it was incorrect. You don't need `const APIUtils =` btw.

Answer (score 1):

importing with curly brackets is for non-default exports.
Since `APIutils` is exported as default, you should import it without the curly brackets.

Edit: here's the explanation from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import#Importing_defaults)

Comment: I see. But something I don't understand is that it works in a previous project I was working on. Do you mind take a look?

Comment: I've just tested it and the example from that project shouldn't work. Might be a bug in the ES6 transpiler you are working with in that project. Maybe check if you are using babel on both + the same version

Comment: but why is the behavior like this? I expect the imported object to be the const `APIUtils` object, and `api.get` and `{get}` both looks for APIUtils.get property isn't it?

Comment: simply because the `get` is not exported, only the `APIUtils` (carrying with him all his properties